# My Hard disk is crashed. How to find the win 8 key which was activated in my laptop?

Tags: windows-8, windows-activation

I had purchased  vaio VPC YA 17GG Laptop with win 7 pro. I have upgraded that 7 to win 8 with upgradation scheme. Now today my HDD crashed. I have changed the hard disk. But I don't know the windows 8 key. How to get it?

Comment: Where did you get the upgrade from?

Comment: As @Kruug suggests, don't you have any emails or other documentation listing the purchased Upgrade key?

Answer (score 2):

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/upgrade-product-key-only

> Have your product key handy. **You can find it in your online order
>   information, in the confirmation email for your purchase, or on the
>   packaging.**

Answer (score 1):

You could connect the crashed drive to another computer and try copying over the config file located in C:\Windows\System32\config . After that you could use any one of the product key locators that are out there on the internet.